# Data Management in R - tidying data after aggregation

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am having difficulty dealing with this step of data management in R while trying to aggregate data at the monthly level.

I have two examples, one essentially represents where I am stuck at now in my process of cleaning and aggregating, and the second represents what I would like it to look like.

What it looks like now:

```
month <- c("January", "January", "February", "March", "April", "April", 
"May", "June", "July")
year <- c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014)
count1 <- c(3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 8, 1, 1, 1)
count2 <- c(0, 2, 1, 4, 6, 0, 1, 1, 1)
count3 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)

df <- data.frame(month, year, count1, count2, count3)
```

What I would like it to look like:

```
month2 <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July")
year2 <- c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014)
count1a <- c(3, 1, 2, 8, 1, 1, 1)
count2a <- c(2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1)
count3a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)

df2 <- data.frame(month2, year2, count1a, count2a, count3a)
```

As you will notice, I am having some months counted twice and their observations are not on the same row as the other observations that I am using for the same month.

Comment: It is somewhat similar. It was not clear how to describe this problem before seeing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'month' and 'year', get the `max`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(month, year) %>%
   summarise_all(max)
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   month [?]
#     month  year count1 count2 count3
#    <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    April  2014      8      6      1
#2 February  2014      1      1      1
#3  January  2014      3      2      1
#4     July  2014      1      1      1
#5     June  2014      1      1      0
#6    March  2014      2      4      1
#7      May  2014      1      1      0
```

If we need to keep the same order, then

```
df %>% 
   group_by(month = factor(month, levels = unique(month)), year) %>% 
   summarise_all(max)
   #or
   #summarise_all(funs(.[order(-.)][1]))
```

Comment: Wow, I did not think of that. This is incredibly HELPFUL!

Comment: Yes definitely the order is important, I appreciate it!